# javascript initialize to undefined or null or ""

Tags: javascript, undefined

Java script has many falsy values as I started learning. I have a program that gets values from a service and loads into an array like this:

```
function loadNames() {
    Global.names = // what should I use here? undefined, null, "", 0, {} or anything else
    var lnames = getLNames(); // this is doing some magic
        if ( lnames.length !== 0 ) {
            Global.names = new Array();
            for ( var i = 0; i < lnames.length; ++i)
                Global.names[i] = lnames[i];
    }
}
```

I want to know the right way of resetting Global.names. What is most appropriate here? In code I only want to check like `if ( Global.names )`

PS: I can't just take the return value into Global.names as the returned object is destroyed later. Hence, I need to do a deep copy

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taken from JavaScript: the good parts :

"The if statement changes the flow of the program based on the value of the expression. The then block is executed if the expression is truthy. Here are the falsy values:

- false
- null
- undefined
- the empty string ''
- the number 0
- the number NaN
  "

So basically if you set your var to any of those values, you'll be able to do a if(var){...}

Answer (score 7):

I think you should init 
`GLobal.names = [];` 
and than just check if `Global.names.length != 0`.
If you want to reset it just make it an empty array again.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd be better off to initialize it as an array and test as

```
if ( Global.names.length )
```

Also, if you're just storing strings in the array you can simplify the function as

```
function loadNames() {
  Global.names = getLNames().concat();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to initialise it to anything. You can do:

```
if (!Global.names) Global.names = [];
// add members to Global.names
```

This can be one in one statement:

```
Global.names = Global.names : [];
```

If you want to reset it, then:

```
Global.names = [];
```

or

```
delete Global.names;
```

Comment: While that's a great example of initialising a variable with a ternary statement, I don't think it quite answers the OP's question, as he is explicitly trying to clear the value of `Global.names`, while your code will not change its value.

Answer (score 1):

Setting it to `null` is good, as you know that the variable exists but hasn't been assigned a value. This way you can easily see the state - if it's `undefined` then you've forgotten to declare it, if it's `null` it has been declared but never assigned a value, and if it's an `Array` then you can test the length from there.

Comment: This is not correct. If the value is `null` then it has been assigned a value (the `null` value). If you don't assign it anything, it will be `undefined`. The language never assigns to `null` implicitly.

Comment: Actually yeah, you're right - what I really meant was that it has been assigned a 'falsy' value which is unlikely to be confused later with a valid value such as `[]`.

Comment: Yes I agree with your approach